# How to Get List of Processes and Store Them in a ListBox, Changing the ListBox Every Time the List of Processes Changes

Tags: c#, winforms, process, listbox

In this situation, I am trying to achieve an effect that is similar to Task Manager. I have a Form (called MainForm) with a ListBox (called listBox1) inside it that I want to store processes inside of. Every time the list of processes changes, I want the ListBox to **automatically** update to include the new list of processes (I don't want to have to press a button to update it).

**What I have tried so far:**

- Threading (I either get a "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on" error or it just doesn't do anything or work
- Timers (These just don't work at all)
- do-while loops (these either freeze the Form or cause it to not load at all)
- BindedLists (these ones actually update the ListBox, but they don't work half of the time)
- Events (These don't work at all)
- Solutions to similar problems found on this site
- Subroutines (Same as do-while loops)
- Recursive Function Calling (Same as do-while loops)
- Creating several different copies of the list of processes and detecting when one changes (this just gets way too complex, confusing, and inefficient)
- ListBox.BeginUpdate() and ListBox.EndUpdate() (These don't work at all)
- ListBox.Refresh() and ListBox.Update() (These aren't very useful)

Here is my code (it is not really necessary since I am technically asking for code):

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (Process proc in processes) {
    if (proc.MainWindowTitle.Length > 0)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Some people have suggested that I look back at the Timer approach. Here is the code for that:

```
// For this example, I will just set it to update every 1/4th of a second.
public static System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(250);
public MainForm {
    InitializeComponent(); // Create the form
    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
}

public static void OnTimedEvent(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) {
    UpdateList();
}

public void UpdateList {
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
    foreach (Process proc in processes) {
        if (proc.MainWindowTitle.Length > 0)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried other various methods, like stopping the timer and then setting it again, but they do not affect it at all. Oddly enough, most of the techniques I have already tried do indeed work in Console Mode (especially Threading and Timers. They just don't seem to work in WinForms).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: take a look at how to add a new item to a listbox first.  that's where you're going wrong

Comment: Perhaps you should show your failed attempts to solve the problem. In particular the first two items in your failed attempts list.

Comment: `Timers (These just don't work at all)` you are using them wrong, `Threading (I either get a "Cross-thread operation not valid: ` you are using them wrong. `do-while loops` this will never work `but they don't work half of the time` you are using them wrong `ListBox.BeginUpdate() and ListBox.EndUpdate()` has nothing to do with this `Events (These don't work at all)` you are using them wrong

Comment: So now that you know you have done just about everything wrong. I suggest we take a look at the timer approach, could you paste the code for that please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a WinForms project, you basically load up your forms/controls and give control back to the OS. Your program won't do anything in the 'main' thread until something happens, like a mouse click, a key press or a timer event.

So during a `while` loop on the 'main' thread you're not giving control back to the OS, and your application seems to hang as you're not giving the OS the chance to even repaint the window.

If you're using `System.Threading.Timer`, `System.Timers.Timer`, or staring your own thread, the code will not run on the 'main' thread and you won't be able to update your controls directly. You can use `Control.BeginInvoke` to queue a message for it, though.

A `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` *will* "tick" on the main thread. I suggest you look into using that one.

Comment: Thank you so much! This has taken literally hours out of my time trying to fix.